# retrieving and display images by tag in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, tags

i iam creating a section with tags with this code, is a function to retrieve tags and exclude some tags also,

```
$args = array('name__like' => $name_like, 'exclude' => array(75,177,42,74,197,36,40,140,162,108,86,47,4,29,22,215,87,151,104),'order' => 'ASC');
         $tags = get_tags( $args );


        if ( !empty( $tags ) && !is_wp_error( $tags ) ) {
            $count = count($tags);
            $i=0;?>

             <ul class="my_term-archive">
             <?php

              foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                $i++;

             $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
             $tag_id =  get_tag_ID($tag->name);
             if(strtolower(substr($tag->name,0,1)) !=$name_like){
                continue;
            }
 //i need a function here to retrieve images with the id of the tag
 //attached


 //////

$html .= "<li><a href='{$tag_link}' id='{$tag_id}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
$html .= "{$tag->name}</a></li>";

              }
         }
         echo $html;
         ?>
         </ul>
```

then i put this code in my functions.php file in wordpress, to make avaliable the tag box in the picture managment, so i can tag pictures now,

```
 function wptp_add_tags_to_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'attachment' );
 }
add_action( 'init' , 'wptp_add_tags_to_attachments' );
```

so my question is how can find and display the images by the id tag ?
sorry my bad english, is not my native lenguage. any help is very welcome. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually handle this with a basic WP_Query call. There's lots of [details and options for the WP_Query object here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters), but I'd think you could do something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'whatever-your-tag-slug-is',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: thanks by point me in the right direction this solution works for me